# How can I use a batch file to create multiple registry backups in the same folder?

Tags: windows-registry, batch-file, regedit

I have a batch file in the Startup folder that creates a backup of the Windows registry using `regedit`. The problem is that it overwrites the older .REG file every time the computer restarts.

Here's the batch file:

```
echo off
regedit /e d:\foo.reg 
exit
```

How can I make it create multiple backup .REG files in the destination folder?

Comment: I will be happy to provide an answer once you explain your question better.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Your question is difficult to understand and shows little effort on your part to resolve this. Please **[edit]** your question to include more details of what you have attempted on your own and where you have got stuck. We will try to help you from there.

Answer (score 3):

Use this instead:

```
@echo off
regedit /e D:\RegBak_%date:/=-%_%time::=-%.reg
exit
```

It will date and time stamp your .REG files so they don't get overwritten each time.